# Problem decoding a JSON string containing "’"

Tags: php, json

My string like this:

```
{
  "key": "value’s",
  "key2": "value"
}
```

I use `json_decode()` PHP 5 and class `Services_Json` for PHP 4 and get nothing when contain "`’`".
What is solution?

Comment: What character encoding does your JSON string use?

Comment: you need to escape single qoute character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your input string isn't properly utf-8 encoded.

http://docs.php.net/json_decode says:

> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

And when I feed it your string utf-8 encoded (i.e. when ’ is encoded as the three-byte-sequence `E2 80 99` instead of `92` in latin1) the result is

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(9) "value’s"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
```

(using php 5.3.3/winxp)

Comment: thank for suggestion, my string was saved with ASNI. I have to save with UTF8- without BOM. Now it's working property